# PHP - Move a file into a different folder on the server

Tags: php, directory, move, unlink

I need to allow users on my website to delete their images off the server after they have uploaded them if they no longer want them. I was previously using the `unlink` function in PHP but have since been told that this can be quite risky and a security issue. (Previous code below:)

```
if(unlink($path.'image1.jpg')){ 
     // deleted
}
```

Instead i now want to simply move the file into a different folder. This must be able to be done a long time after they have first uploaded the file so any time they log into their account. If i have the main folder which stores the users image(s):

```
user/
```

and then within that a folder called del which is the destination to put their unwanted images:

```
user/del/
```

Is there a command to move a file into a different folder? So that say:

```
user/image1.jpg
```

moves to/becomes

```
user/del/image1.jpg
```

Answer (score 524, accepted):

The `rename` function does this

[docs rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)

`rename('image1.jpg', 'del/image1.jpg');`

If you want to keep the existing file on the same place you should use `copy`

[docs copy](http://php.net/copy)

`copy('image1.jpg', 'del/image1.jpg');`

If you want to move an uploaded file use the `move_uploaded_file`, although this is almost the same as `rename` this function also checks that the given file is a file that was uploaded via the `POST`, this prevents for example that a local file is moved

[docs move_uploaded_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

```
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
```

**code snipet from docs**

Comment: One problem with rename() and copy() is you lost all the metadata such as created and modified date for example.. have that in mind.

Comment: The downside of `rename()` is that it doesn't actually moves the file as you expect. You'll need to use something like `basename()` or `pathinfo()` to retrieve the filename in order to store the file in the new directory with the same name.

Answer (score 121):

Use the [rename()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) function.

```
rename("user/image1.jpg", "user/del/image1.jpg");
```

Answer (score 32):

If you want to move the file in new path with keep original file name. use this:

```
$source_file = 'foo/image.jpg';
$destination_path = 'bar/';
rename($source_file, $destination_path . pathinfo($source_file, PATHINFO_BASENAME));
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Comment: If you want to change the file name you can do it simply like this `rename("/tmp/tmp_file.txt", "/home/user/login/docs/my_file.txt");`

Answer (score 2):

Some solution is first to copy() the file (as mentioned above) and when the destination file exists - unlink() file from previous localization. Additionally you can validate the MD5 checksum before unlinking to be sure

Answer (score 2):

I using shell read all data file then assign to array.
Then i move file in top position.

```
i=0 
for file in /home/*.gz; do
    $file
    arr[i]=$file
    i=$((i+1)) 
done 
mv -f "${arr[0]}" /var/www/html/
```

Comment: Please explain that further - how could this work using PHP?

Answer (score 2):

Use file this code

```
function move_file($path,$to){
   if(copy($path, $to)){
      unlink($path);
      return true;
   } else {
     return false;
   }
 }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, this to me is perfect. rename() is fine but it changes the file.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to move it:

```
function move_file($file, $to){
    $path_parts = pathinfo($file);
    $newplace   = "$to/{$path_parts['basename']}";
    if(rename($file, $newplace))
        return $newplace;
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function xmove($src,$dst)
{

  if(is_dir($src)===true)
  { $dir=opendir($src);
    while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
        if ($file === '.' || $file === '..') {
            continue;
        }

        if (is_dir($src."/".$file) === true) {
            if (is_dir("$dst/$file") === false) {
                mkdir("$dst/$file");
            }
            //echo basename("$file")."<br>";
                xmove($src."/".$file,$dst."/".$file);
            
        }
        else {
            copy("$src/$file", "$dst/$file");
            unlink("$src/$file");
            
        }
    }

    closedir($dir);
    rmdir($src);
    return true;

  }else
  return false;

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

use **copy()** and **unlink()** function

```
$moveFile="path/filename";
if (copy($csvFile,$moveFile)) 
{
  unlink($csvFile);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

shell_exec('mv filename dest_filename');

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!