# how to move image from one folder to another folder in php as No error in

Tags: php

i use the following code to move image one folder to another folder but it does not work.

as follows

```
if(file_exists('admin/passenger_photo/p1.jpg'))
{
    rename('admin/passenger_photo/p1.jpg' , 'admin/driver_photo/p1.jpg');
    echo "success";
}
```

but yet it does not work.
thanks & regards

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Have you checked your script's permissions for reading and writing from and to the respective directories?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Move a file into a different folder on the server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139434/php-move-a-file-into-a-different-folder-on-the-server)

Comment: `file_exists` requires full base path of the file, so as `rename` to rename it..try giving full path to both functions and it will work like a charm..

Comment: `http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php`..

Comment: by full path i got error Warning: rename(localhost/chauffers/admin/passenger_photo/p1.jpg,localhost/chauffers/admin/driver_photo/p1.jpg) [function.rename]: No error in C:\wamp\www\chauffers\passenger_user.php on line 252

Comment: @user3342546 it's not absolute path, you must use real file system path, not url. Something like file_exists('/var/www/html/chauffers/admin/passenger_photo/p1.jpg')

Comment: if i used like this  rename('http://localhost/chauffers/admin/passenger_photo/p1.jpg' , 'http://localhost/chauffers/admin/driver_photo/p1.jpg');  i get error  Warning: rename() [function.rename]: http wrapper does not support renaming in C:\wamp\www\chauffers\passenger_user.php on line 251

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script works fine in my lab. Possible check the permission environment and file permission.