# PHP: Copying and moving image

Tags: php, file-upload

As the title says, how do I copy an image which directory is this:

```
img/user.png
```

and let's say we want to copy this image to

```
user_files/username/putfilehere.png
```

I've found some really long routes to this, but I believe it can be achieved with a couple of lines of code.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139434/php-move-a-file-into-a-different-folder-on-the-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume our script is located in directory /www/ and you want to copy image from /www/img/user.png to /www/user_files/username/putfilehere.png. In that case it's pretty easy to do:

```
copy('./img/user.png', './user_files/username/putfilehere.png');
```