# How can I transfer one php file to another folder before uploading the file

Tags: php

I need to transfer one php file to another folder.
For example:

I have a folder naming sample inside it there are two folders naming folderA and folderB, inside folderA there is folderC and inside it there are folders 1,2 and 3 and `test.php` the file 
I need to transfer is inside folder 3... 
So I need to transfer it in folderB ...

I have already tried to transfer it and also I have changed the path for each include and require that I used... but still there is an error..

> Fatal error: Class `'C_test'` not found in
>   `/var/www/html/sample/folderA/folderC/folder3/trial.php` on line 68

Class `C_test` is inside `test.php`

I think there is a problem regarding my autoload function..?
here is my codes for my autoload function..

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../../.');    

function __autoload($className){
    $filePath = str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';
    $includePaths = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path());
    foreach($includePaths as $includePath){
        if(file_exists($includePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filePath)){
            require_once $filePath;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I need help...

Comment: whats the reason to transfer the php file ? is there any specific reason ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Move a file into a different folder on the server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139434/php-move-a-file-into-a-different-folder-on-the-server)

Comment: Sir the reason is I need to upload that specific file to our server that is why I need to transfer it. Does it make sense?