# Relocate csv file to different directory

Tags: php, mysql

Does someone knows how to transfer a csv file to another directory? And from its previous location it should be remove. Please show me a code or keyword on how to transfer a csv file.

Thanks

Comment: Try phps `rename` function: http://php.net/manual/de/function.rename.php

Comment: thanks! buddy! got it! what about comparing data types of each fields of table and csv columns if they have the same data type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Move a file into a different folder on the server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139434/php-move-a-file-into-a-different-folder-on-the-server)

Comment: yeah! i just found that thread. my new question is how to compare db table fields and csv columns