# Laravel 5 moving image to another folder dynamically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a fileupload module in my app. I can upload files in img/upload/{container_id}/file_name_here.

The {container_id} will depend on what folder the user will use.

The problem I encountered is when they try to edit a record to another folder. The file that they uploaded remains in the old folder.

I want to move the file also to the new folder the user defines.

I have here my code, I'm stuck in moving the file.

```
$attachments = Attachment::where('document_id',$id)->select('filename')->get();
        $document = Document::findOrFail($id);

        foreach($attachments as $attachment)
        {
            $attachment->filename = base_path().'/public/img/upload/'.$document->container_id."/".$attachment->filename;
        }

        Document::findOrFail($id)->update($request->all());

        $document = Document::findOrFail($id);

        $x = Attachment::where('document_id','=',$id)->count();

        foreach($attachments as $file)
        {

            HOW_DO_I_MOVE_THE_FILE????
            $x++;
        }

        return redirect('documents');
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/filesystem#storing-files take a look at the move() method

Comment: but I'm not using the storage facades

Comment: anyway take a look at this question seems duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139434/php-move-a-file-into-a-different-folder-on-the-server

Comment: @AmirBar now I'm thinking of using storage facades now, since I think its more simpler than my method. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

In your case, you should use `rename()`:

```
rename ('current/path/to/foo', 'new/path/to/foo');
```

With rename() you can not only rename, but also move! Simply, if the path of the second param differs. So you can use in your loop the attachment path as first param, and a destination path as second.

Documentation: http://php.net/rename

*Below the Laravel approach for moving after upload.*

From the documentation:

```
$request->file('photo')->move($destinationPath);

$request->file('photo')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
```

`photo` is the name of your file upload input element.

Note, you can use the array notation, if you've multi upload, such as:

```
foreach ($request->file('photo') as $photo)
{
    $photo->move($destinationPath, $chooseYourFileName);
}
```

Comment: I have tried that, but got error since $fileName which is in the $attachments is not actually a file but a 'path' to a file