# Moving file from one place to another

Tags: php, file, rename

I am trying to move a file from one place to another with PHP. All of my attempts have failed. I have tried:

```
rename("C:\Users\Eli\Desktop\NEWWAMP\wamp\www\Tyler\whaley.html", "C:\Users\Eli\Desktop\NEWWAMP\wamp\www\Tyler\Games\whaley.html");
```

and:

```
rename("whaley.html", "Games/whaley.html");
```

and I get errors for both of those.

See the link for a visual of my problem.

[My problem](http://104.58.136.201:4444/Tyler/prob.webm)

Comment: does the user running php have write access on the file/directory ?

Comment: 1. What error, 2. Use absolute paths.

Comment: @Robert he used absolute paths in the first example.

Comment: Please post the _exact_ error message you receive.

Comment: Have you tried using: "C:\\Users\\Eli\\Desktop\\NEWWAMP\\wamp\\www\\Tyler\\whaley.htm" ?

Comment: @BobNocraz these are absolute on windows only when he uploads this to server that is based on linux it won't work, I suggest `realpath()` with `__FILE__` or `__DIR__`

Comment: @Robert ok, makes sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Move a file into a different folder on the server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139434/php-move-a-file-into-a-different-folder-on-the-server)

Answer (score 0):

```
copy (string source, string dest)
```

Comment: copy does not move file it copies file as the name of function says

Comment: Moving is *almost* the same as copying and then removing the source file. :)

Comment: @Mitch not quite because manual says http://php.net/rename "Attempts to rename oldname to newname, moving it between directories if necessary"