# Laravel - Upload multiple files from request and move them to a folder

Tags: php, laravel

So I tried file uploading using Input but sadly failed. I am trying to use `Request` to do it but I get the follow error:

> Call to a member function move() on string

blade:

```
<input type="file" name="productImage[]" id="" multiple>
```

controller:

```
public function addProduct(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'details' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'subcategory' => 'required',
        'color' => 'min:1',
        'size' => 'min:1',
        'productImage' => 'min:1'
    ]);

    $product = new Product();
    $product->subcategory_id = $request['subcategory'];
    $product->gender_id = $request['gender'];
    $product->title = $request['title'];
    $product->description = $request['description'];
    $product->details = $request['details'];
    $product->price = $request['price'];
    $product->save();

    foreach ($request['color'] as $color_id) {
        $color = Color::find($color_id);
        $product->colors()->save($color);
    }

    foreach ($request['size'] as $size_id) {
        $size = Size::find($size_id);
        $product->sizes()->save($size);
    }

    foreach ($request->file('productImage') as $productImage) {
        $file = $productImage;
        $file->move('images', $file->getClientOriginalName());
        $image = new Image();
        $image->product_id = $product->id;
        $image->path = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $product->images()->save($image);
    }

    return redirect()->route('admin.products')->with(['added' => 'Продукт добавен успешно!']);
}
```

I need to get my files and their names and upload them to my images folder.

Answer (score 1):

Your $productImage is a string, not a file.

```
$files = Input::file('productImage');
foreach($files as $file) {
    $file->move(...);
    ....
```

Comment: I tried this solution before asking the question. I get -Invalid argument supplied for foreach()-

Comment: Show us your controller code. You're probably making some mistake there.

Comment: I edited my question. You can see my controller there.

Comment: Make sure you are creating your form properly: `{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'my_url','method'=>'POST', 'files'=>true)) !!}`. `Files = true` should be there. Or `enctype="multipart/form-data"` if you are not using blade.

Comment: I am not using Form I am writing just as it is. What should I change to make it work or is it neccessary to use Form?
<input type="file" name="productImage[]"  multiple>

Comment: How are you sending data to backend? With ajax?

Comment: I am not using AJAX. I send it via php. Do I have to use AJAX?

Comment: That's the problem, you need to wrap your "input" with form tags. If you are using Laravel 5+, check this: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112280/discussion-between-codearts-and-felippe-duarte).

Answer (score 0):

You could use Felippe Duarte's solution or get all files uploaded with the `Request` as well, calling to file method like this:

```
foreach ($request->file('productImage') as $productImage) {
    $file = $productImage;
    $file->move('images', $file->getClientOriginalName());
    $image = new Image();
    $image->product_id = $product->id;
    $image->path = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $product->images()->save($image);
}
```

Comment: I tried his solution before asking the question. With both yours and his I get -Invalid argument supplied for foreach()-

Comment: @Codearts make sure you have `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` at the top of your class, what laravel version are you using?

Comment: I do use them though.

Comment: @Codearts how is your `form` tag?

Answer (score -1):

Try using `move_uploaded_file` instead of `move`.

Try checking out this link : [PHP - Move a file into a different folder on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139434/php-move-a-file-into-a-different-folder-on-the-server)

It is explained more detailed.