# Can I programmatically change the path to the file using PHP?

Tags: php, file, path, filepath

Can I programmatically change the path to a file using PHP?

For example, change `D:\ISO & SOFT\test.txt` to `D:\test.txt`.

Comment: You can change directory within the exec command ( **exec("cd Scripts && ./script.sh")** ) or you change the working directory of the PHP process using chdir().

Comment: Do you want to move the file [ _test.txt_ ] from D:\ISO & SOFT\  to D:/ ?

Comment: If you want to move the file then your questions is a duplicate.
This question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19139524/2231819).
The current answer of @PrabhuNandanKumar was also stolen from there. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose you can simple move the file from the present path to the desired path.

Use the following steps for moving a file in PHP:

```
$uploads_dir = '/uploads'; // Desired path
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name"); //Moving file at desire path
    }
}
```