# How to get hidden errors of move uploaded file?

Tags: php

I have this php code:

```
move_uploaded_file($_POST["filelocation"], "dock/images/".explode("upload/",$_POST["filelocation"])[1]);
putindb();
```

And the `putindb` function works fine, I don't get any error, but the file isn't copied. How can i see what error is behind this? Or how can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you looked at your PHP error logs?

Comment: @Martin I can't see any error, just a blank page...

Comment: did you actually look in your PHP error log (**NOT** your output page)?

Comment: @Martin nont, how can I see that?

Comment: [try here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel) to find your PHP error log file.

Comment: @Martin nothing there too at this timecode

Comment: You're concatenating a string to an array: `"dock/images/".explode("upload/...` Do `echo '<pre>'; print_r($_FILES); exit;` to see what you're working with when the upload is submitted.

Comment: @JaredFarrish the `$_FILES` is an empty array because I don't have any upload form here. This is just a page what have to move this file.

Comment: You might want to read the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php - you can't use that function to just move random files on the server. You would use [rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) for that.

Comment: @TiesonT. you have right! Thank you, you resolved a very big problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `$_FILES` superglobal to get the file paths `$_FILES['nameOfFileInputField']['tmp_name']` that will give you the path where the file is.

In your form you should have something like:

```
<form method="POST" action="whatever.php">
    <input type="file" name="nameOfFileInputField" />
</form>
```

The type of the input field should be **file**.

Comment: An example of the code edit required might help....

Comment: But this isn't in a form, I don't get file upload, I just have to move files to other directory.

Comment: @kortealma Yeah, when you move an uploaded file, you're not dealing with the `POST` array, you're working with the `$_FILES` superglobal, which has a path to the temporary file that stores the contents of a given field in the upload. This is what you need to move. I would also whitelist the path to move it to.

Comment: @JaredFarrish but then I don't have `nameOfFileInputField` how can I use than `$_FILES`?

Comment: I have it but not this script makes the form upload. This script only have to move the file to other directory, this is used by an other page where isn't any file upload, just want to use the uploaded files. The files might be uploaded other time.

Comment: You can't use `move_uploaded_file()` function to move files in a directory. That ounly moves uploaded files, as the name suggests. You can try this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139434/php-move-a-file-into-a-different-folder-on-the-server