# File move to another folder laravel

Tags: laravel, file, move

I need the last 7 days' storage logs to move a new folder. But, I can't move them and got this error.

> rename(/var/www/html/eMarketing/storage/logs/old-log-2020-02-27,/var/www/html/eMarketing/storage/logs/laravel-2020-02-27.log): Not a directory

My Code is here

```
public function logs() 
{
  $today = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d');
  $days  = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(7)->format('Y-m-d');

  $newDirectoryPath = storage_path('logs/old-log-'.$days);
  if (!\File::isDirectory($newDirectoryPath)) {
      \File::makeDirectory($newDirectoryPath);
  }

  $path = storage_path('logs/');
  $allFiles = \File::allFiles($path);

  foreach($allFiles as $files) {
      $file = pathinfo($files);
      $logDay = str_replace('laravel-','', $file['filename']);  

      if ($logDay >= $days && $logDay < $today) {
          \File::move($newDirectoryPath, $path.$file['basename']);
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: Does the `/var/www/html/eMarketing/storage/logs` directory exist?

Comment: yes, this directory exist @Jerodev

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139434/php-move-a-file-into-a-different-folder-on-the-server   Does this answer your question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem

The problem is, **you don't have files to move**.

```php
$newDirectoryPath = storage_path('logs/old-log-' . $days);

if (!\File::isDirectory($newDirectoryPath)) {
    \File::makeDirectory($newDirectoryPath);
}
```

The `move()` method may be used to rename or move an existing file to a new location. But 
`$newDirectoryPath` is a folder not a file.

---

#### Solution

You need to change :

```php
\File::move(
    $path . $file['basename'],                  // old file
    $newDirectoryPath . '/' . $file['basename'] // new file
);
```

```
public function logs()
{
    $today = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d');
    $days  = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(7)->format('Y-m-d');

    $newDirectoryPath = storage_path('logs/old-log-' . $days);
    if (!\File::isDirectory($newDirectoryPath)) {
        \File::makeDirectory($newDirectoryPath);
    }

    $path     = storage_path('logs/');
    $allFiles = \File::allFiles($path);

    foreach ($allFiles as $files) {
        $file   = pathinfo($files);
        $logDay = str_replace('laravel-', '', $file['filename']);

        if ($logDay >= $days && $logDay < $today) {
            \File::move($path . $file['basename'], $newDirectoryPath . '/' . $file['basename']);
        }

    }
}
```